# how to make long line as pep8 compatible in python?

Tags: python

I have different lines like this how can i make these kind of lines as pep8 compatible?

```
messbycircle_freq_result['percentage']=
messbycircle_freq_result['smstext']/sum(messbycircle_freq_result['smstext'])
```

> ERROR1: line too long
>
> ERROR2: unexpected indentation

and also facing so many problems for the below as well

buckets = np.where(tobebuckets <= 0, 0,
                        np.where(np.logical_and(tobebuckets>0,
                                              tobebuckets<=10), 10,                        np.where(np.logical_and(tobebuckets>10,tobebuckets<=50),
                               50, np.where(np.logical_and(tobebuckets>50,                                                          tobebuckets<=100), 100,                                    np.where(np.logical_and(tobebuckets>100,                                                          tobebuckets<=500), 500,                                    np.where(np.logical_and(tobebuckets>500,                                                         tobebuckets<=1000),1000,1001))))))

please help me for the above code like the earlier one.thank you very much for the earlier.

Comment: You can split a line and use the line continuation character `\ `. A line continuation character isn't necessary if you are in an open parenthesis `(`, brace `{` or square bracket `[`. I also find 80 characters a bit too constricting so often relax this to 120 characters.

Comment: Even after following your steps i am getting the errors like following vf_todo_2.py:29:14: E128 continuation line under-indented for visual indent

Comment: When using a continuation character you should indent the next line by 4 spaces, if you are in an open bracket then line it up on the bracket.

Comment: i am following as you said and my code is same as adarsh 1st answer.Even though i am getting the same error

Comment: Post what you've tried

Comment: you want me to post in comments or where?

Comment: Or else i have posted my 'buckets' code in body. can you please rewrite that code as pep8 compatible like @adarsh answer.please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not easy to nest this many calls and keep it under 80 characters, why don't you break them up (to keep under 80 characters you still need to split the lines):

```
buckets1000 = np.where(np.logical_and(tobebuckets > 500, tobebuckets <= 1000),
                       1000, 1001)
buckets500 = np.where(np.logical_and(tobebuckets > 100, tobebuckets <= 500),
                      500, buckets1000)
buckets100 = np.where(np.logical_and(tobebuckets > 50, tobebuckets <= 100),
                      100, buckets500)
buckets50 =  np.where(np.logical_and(tobebuckets > 10, tobebuckets <= 50),
                      50, buckets100)
buckets10 = np.where(np.logical_and(tobebuckets > 0, tobebuckets <= 10),
                     10, buckets50)
buckets = np.where(tobebuckets <= 0, 0, buckets10)
```

Or you can force it on one line:

```
buckets = np.where(
    tobebuckets <= 0, 0,
    np.where(
        np.logical_and(tobebuckets > 0, tobebuckets <= 10), 10,
        np.where(
            np.logical_and(tobebuckets > 10,tobebuckets <= 50), 50,
            np.where(
                np.logical_and(tobebuckets > 50, tobebuckets <= 100), 100,
                np.where(
                    np.logical_and(tobebuckets > 100, tobebuckets <= 500), 500,
                    np.where(
                        np.logical_and(tobebuckets > 500, tobebuckets <= 1000),
                        1000, 1001))))))
```

Neither of which are desperately attractive code.

You can abstract out the where clause into a recursive function:

```
def where(s, l):
    if not l:
        return s+1
    return np.where(np.logical_and(tobebuckets > s, tobebuckets <= l[0]),
                    l[0], where(l[0], l[1:]))

buckets = np.where(tobebuckets <= 0, 0, where(0, [10, 50, 100, 500, 1000]))
```

Comment: WOW! Thank you very much.Every thing is all right but it is showing undefined name 'mean' .when i am using this command,can you help me on this  textranges_freq = textrangesdata.groupby('buckets').agg(mean)

Comment: That's a separate question, if you still need help, suggest starting another question.

Comment: it's okay i just make it as pep8 compatible by changing the code to textranges_freq = textrangesdata.groupby('buckets').mean()

Comment: Is there any other easy way to write the code which is similar to the above

Answer (score 2):

```
(
    messbycircle_freq_result['percentage'] = 
    messbycircle_freq_result['smstext'] /
    sum(messbycircle_freq_result['smstext'])
)
```

Basically you need to keep all lines less than 80 characters.

So there are more ways you can do this too,

```
messbycircle_freq_result['percentage'] = (
    messbycircle_freq_result['smstext'] /
    sum(messbycircle_freq_result['smstext'])
)
```

etc.

Comment: Thank you very much.Every thing is all right but it is showing undefined name 'mean' .when i am using this command,      textranges_freq = textrangesdata.groupby('buckets').agg(mean)       can you help me on this

Answer (score 1):

```
def calculate_percentage(result):
    result['percentage'] = result['smstext'] / sum(result['smstext'])

calculate_percentage(messbycircle_freq_result)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Short convenience variables** -- used strategically in narrowly defined sections of code -- can do wonders to reduce visual overload, and thus increase readability, without sacrificing clarity.

This example illustrates that idea and builds on the answer from achampion.

```
mfr = messbycircle_freq_result
mfr['percentage'] = mfr['smstext'] / sum(mfr['smstext'])

tbb     = tobebuckets
bs1000  = np.where(np.logical_and(tbb > 500, tbb <= 1000), 1000, 1001)
bs500   = np.where(np.logical_and(tbb > 100, tbb <= 500), 500, bs1000)
bs100   = np.where(np.logical_and(tbb > 50, tbb <= 100), 100, bs500)
bs50    = np.where(np.logical_and(tbb > 10, tbb <= 50), 50, bs100)
bs10    = np.where(np.logical_and(tbb > 0, tbb <= 10), 10, bs50)
buckets = np.where(tbb <= 0, 0, bs10)
```